# Symfony2 findAll from entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

The query

```
$apartats = $em->getRepository('MyCompanyFrontendBundle:User')->findAll();
```

returns me an array with the same value in all values.

The numer of objects of returned array are good, but all values are equal than the first row of the table.

Example:

```
id:1, name:"Peter"  
id:2, name="Sofia"  
id:3, name="David"
```

Returns me:

```
id:1, name:"Peter"  
id:1, name:"Peter"  
id:1, name:"Peter"
```

Why is this?

Comment: how did you show your result? var_dump? Twig? Can you give us more information? (Entity code, function where you do your findAll,...)

Answer (score -1):

Check user entity's annotation

if it is look like this

```
/**
     * @var boolean $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
```

change it to

```
/**
         * @var integer $id
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
         */
```

and also check  user.orm.yml file .